# getline(stream, string) from example is rejected by editor(VS2019)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The example is taken from:
[http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/languages/C++/1AComputing/Mich/index.php?reply=extraReadingfromfiles#extraReadingfromfilesanchor][1]

I wrote the code without the while loop to read file, the example used `getline(stream, strgvar)`, but this is not admited by the editor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string message;
    ifstream fin;       // variable to store information about a file
    fin.open("s.txt");      // trying to open file for reading
    //  next line would try to check if file has been opened succesfully
    if (not fin.good())
    {
        cout << "\n\t Couldn't open the s file." << endl;
        cout << "\n\t It needs to be in the same folder as your program." 
             <<endl;
        return 1;       // In the main function this line quits from the 
                        whole program.
    }
    // we have menaged to open the file. Now we'll read a line from the file into the string
    while (message!="works!")
    {
        fin >> message;
        cout << message << " ";
    }
    //getline(fin,message);
}
```

My questions is why the line now commented is rejected ?

Comment: Unrelated: consider changing the code around a bit to `while (fin >> message && message != "works!") { cout << message << " "; }`. Putting the read inside the while condition makes sure data was indeed read before testing the value that was read. Always read, validate, then use.

Comment: You need to `#include <string>` for  that version of the `getline` function. Mind you, you should `#include <string>` for the `string` class itself, but I guess your compiler let you get away with that.

Comment: Visual studio...  Missed that tag. Visual studio is getting very very angry over the missing header. May also get angry over `not`.

Comment: user4581301 -   I had tryed meanwhile another example and it looks like VS2019 at least has an issue about this, and thanks to remember me about read, validate, use !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fin>>message;
The stream extraction operator '>>' is used when you want to read a single word from file. 
Find complete explanation at : https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpp-program-read-file-word-word/amp/

While
getline(fin,message); 
In this, a full line from the file will be read in message variable. It will continue reading and assigning file contents till a '\n' (Line Deliminator) character does not appear. And thats why you getline() statement is rejected.
For complete explanation visit : http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/48212/

Your program is expected to read a word at a time. And to accomplish this, fin>>mesage is used. Basically stream extraction operator read the contents till a space appears, and hence it is used to read single word.

And if you still want to use getline (), then add a third parameter to your function call as space character ' '.
Like 
getline(fin,message,' '); // and done
Basically the third parameter of getline function is Deliminator, by default it is '\n', but if you want to define your own Deliminator, you can do so by providing third parameter. It will read the contents of file till the Deliminator does not occurs while reading.

Comment: I know the places you referenced, but not those examples, it's so big quantity of items   sometimes can't achieve to find the best ones, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To use `std::getline()` include `<string>` in the header. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/2whx1zkx(v=vs.100)

`istream` also has a getline. More details here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa277361(v=vs.60)